# Can I use gitosis/gitolite alongside SmartHTTP to commit to repos?

Tags: git, authentication, gitosis

Background on my situation is this: I'm a long-time Windows and Linux user and in the past few years I've moved exclusively to Windows for my user-facing computers and Ubuntu server for my servers.  I'm moving into a new research position where I cannot avoid using Mac.  However, I have set up all the Git repos on my server to be read/writeable using Smart HTTP and I let Apache handle my authentication.  All of the connections are over SSL.

I have not yet found a free-ware client on MacOS (well, any GUI Git client) that will handle Apache's authentication.  So, I have two solutions to my problem.  The first is the identification of a free/cheap Git GUI for MacOS that can handle HTTPS and authentication over HTTP.  If you know of one, awesome, please tell me.  However, I am still interested to know the answer to scenario 2.

The second is to try to use gitosis to do my authentication using keys.  If I pursue that path, I need to be able to leave the HTTP authentication alone for legacy purposes (and, frankly, to ease my key management my only having to manage the keys for my own Mac machines).  I'm not well-versed enough in gitosis to know if I can push commits to a repo both through gitosis and using Smart HTTP.  If anyone can shed light on whether or not this would be possible, that would be great.  An example of how to do it would be exponentially better, and a solution that also allowed commits over SSH would be the absolute cherry on top.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Gitosis or Gitolite **won't do any authentication** (and please use [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite). Gitolsis is obsolete).
They only do **authorization**: see "[authentication versus authorisation](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/pu/doc/authentication-vs-authorisation.mkd)".

That being said, you can [setup Gitolite with smart http](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/pu/doc/http-backend.mkd) (it is not *just* linked with ssh, it supports other authentication mechanisms).